# Two constructors in a Python Class

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is it OK to have 2 constructor functions, the regular `__init__` and a `@classmethod` `Animal.get`?

Since creating a new object is computationally intensive, we want to store previously created instances in a class attribute `cls.zoo` and get a cached copy of the instance from `cls.zoo` if it exists.

The user will not access `Animal.zoo` directly. If the user wants to get an `Animal` object, he will always use `Animal.get()`.

Is this approach proper/pythonic?

I'm not familiar with the Singleton Pattern. Is the code considered using the Singleton Pattern?

```
class Animal:

    zoo = {}

    # will not be called directly from outside the class
    def __init__(self, species ,age):
        self.species = species
        self.age = age
        self.runExpensiveFunction()

    # User alway use this function
    @classmethod
    def get(cls, species):
        if species in cls.zoo:
            animal = cls.zoo[species]
        else:
            animal = Animal(species, 0)
            cls.zoo[species] = animal

        return animal

tiger = Animal.get('tiger')
bear = Animal.get('bear')
```

Comment: If this is working code that you think could be improved, consider [codereview.se] (although they will want actual code, not a dummy example).

Comment: Is this real code? It appears that it could be demo/play code, which would be off-topic for Code Review.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with alternative constructors via classmethods, on the contrary.

Comment: This is demo/play code, so I posted to SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends whether you just want to allow the user of your class to access a cached object, or if you want to force it to only access that cached object. With you solution, user can always use `tiger2 = Animal('tiger', 0)` to get another instance.

If you really want only one instance, you can use `__new__`:

```
class Animals(object):
    zoo = {}
    def runExpensiveFunction(self):
        print "EXPENSIVE CALLED"
    def __new__(cls, species):
        if species in cls.zoo:
            return cls.zoo[species]
        else:
            animal = object.__new__(Animals)
            animal.species = species
            animal.age = 0
            animal.runExpensiveFunction()
            Animals.zoo[species] = animal
            return animal
```

Here is the proof that you can only create one instance:

```
>>> tiger1 = Animals('tiger')
EXPENSIVE CALLED
>>> tiger2 = Animals('tiger')
>>> tiger2 is tiger1
True
```

Comment: The user is forced to use the cache object if it is available. In this case, how will you decide when to use `__new__` vs. the `classmethod`?

Comment: @Nyxynyx : with the class method, the user can always create a new object without using it. The `__new__` method is called for each new instance. So if you want to always use the cache, `__new__` is more secure.